# html and href click only once

Tags: html, href

I have a link

```
<a href="new link">click me</a>
```

when a user click the link "click me", the new link page will be redirected and do something at the server side. The problem, if a user click the back button on the browser, it will go back to the old link. If the user click the link "click me", the new link page will be opened and processing at the server side will do again. How to prevent this situation? That is even a user go back to the old page, the new link cannot be clicked anymore

Comment: Could you be a little more clear in your question?

Comment: Why don't you prevent users to go back to that page? I personally only rely upon the server-side attributes to do that.

Comment: Time to learn about idempotency. Moral of the story: use a proper `<form>` with `method="post"`, and use the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a unique id on the link, like `therequest.do?id=1234`, and log `1234` to a database so that the request cannot be run again.

- User goes to `mypage.do`, server generates id `1234` and logs to database as unprocessed.
- User clicks link to `therequest.do?id=1234`
- Server does processing, and marks id `1234` as processed.
- User clicks back button.
- User clicks link again.
- Server checks and sees request `1234` is already processed, so generates an error message on the screen: `request has already been processed`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a new window and that would prevent end user from being able to go back however, you would need to create visited state to make the button disappear in the CSS.

```
<a href="new link" target="_blank">click me</a>
```

Other then that in pure HTML there is no way to stop a user from hitting the back button on a standard link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Javascript.  Here's example code that shows one way to do it:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="f();">click me</a>
<script>
    var first = true;
    function f() {
        if ( first ) {
            first = false;
            window.open('http://www.google.com');
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you could get rid of the global state variable and just disable or hide the link once it's clicked.